# How are the pre-compiled mitmproxy binaries actually built?

Tags: mitmproxy

I was hoping someone could shine some light on this for me. I'm trying to understand how Python is compiled into a single executable. Mainly I'm just curious, given that I haven't seen many project that do this as cleanly as mitmproxy.

I looked in the documentation, and didn't find anything (although I could have missed it) and while I did see references to packaging python for distribution in setup.py, I didn't find anything that talks about building a single file for distribution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In a nutshell, our GitHub Actions CI workers invoke PyInstaller to create the binaries and then upload them to an S3 bucket that lies behind https://mitmproxy.org/downloads/.

The most relevant parts in the codebase are:

- https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/blob/bbc2cf331a4ab180001668bf4b51eeec505e01ab/.github/workflows/main.yml#L84-L111
- https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/blob/bbc2cf331a4ab180001668bf4b51eeec505e01ab/release/cibuild.py#L372-L450

(The whole process also is a giant PITA. If you can avoid it, avoid it. We hopefully reach the point where tools like PyOxidizer become mature enough to be usable, but that hasn't been the case yet)

Comment: WOW! Thanks for the crazy fast response! I appreciate pointing me in the right direction. I'll take a look at this and post any additional questions.